# How can I tell if a checkbox was actually clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a binding for multiple inputs.

```
$("#foo", "#bar", "#fooCheckbox", "#barCheckBox").bind("change", function() {
   // do something here
   // do something extra here if $(this) was actually clicked
});
```

Since there are other ways of initiating a change of an input, (jquery's .change() method for one), Is there a way to tell if a checkbox was actually clicked to cause the change event?

I tried focus however the focus event fires before a checkbox's change event so that doesn't work.

```
$("#foo", "#bar", "#fooCheckbox", "#barCheckBox").bind("change", function() {
   // do something here
   if($(this).is(":focus")) // do something extra here but focus doesn't happen here for checkboxes.
});
```

**Edit #1**

Sorry I don't really know how to clarify this further...I don't care if the checkbox is checked or not...I know what .is(":checked") is and how to use it.  It doesn't help here.  I only want to know if the checkbox was actually clicked in to trigger the change event.

**Edit #2**

I have a work around...I first bind clicks for inputs and selects and store the id of the element.  Then in my change binding I check to see if the element that changed is the same element that was last clicked.

```
$("input, select").click(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    lastClickedStore.lastClicked = myId;
});
```

Then in the change binding I just check if the current ID equals the last clicked Id.

```
$("#foo", "#bar", "#fooCheckbox", "#barCheckBox").bind("change", function() {
   // do something
   if(lastClickedStore.lastClicked == $(this).attr("id")) // do something else.
}
```

Comment: Maybe the $(this.id) will help you identify it. Check my edited answer. Sorry if I am going in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I solved this problem.  I first bind clicks for inputs and selects and store the id of the element.  Then in my change binding I check to see if the element that changed is the same element that was last clicked.

```
$("input, select").click(function() {
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    lastClickedStore.lastClicked = myId;
});
```

Then in the change binding I just check if the current ID equals the last clicked Id.

```
$("#foo", "#bar", "#fooCheckbox", "#barCheckBox").bind("change", function() {
   // do something
   if(lastClickedStore.lastClicked == $(this).attr("id")) // do something else.
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Bind to `click` instead of `change`. The `click` event will still be triggered when the check box's state is changed with the keyboard, but [event.pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [event.pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) will be `0` in that case, so you can write:

```
$("#foo, #bar, #fooCheckbox, #barCheckBox").click(function(event) {
    // Do something here...
    if (event.pageX > 0) {
        // Check box was clicked, do something extra here...
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting...It doesn't quite get me what I need though.  The binding to "change" is for a reason.  Click doesn't mean change every time, especially in this situation where #foo is a select box.  However, all that being said, excellent idea about the pageX, I will have to incorporate that.

Answer (score 1):

Frédéric Hamidi answer is good. But if you want to raise an event 'change' programmatically, then his code is, unfortunately, will not work. If you really want what you described, try this version:

```
$('#foo, #bar').bind({
    click: function () {
        alert('click ' + this.id);
        if ($(this).hasClass('changed')) {
            alert('click+change ' + this.id);
            $(this).removeClass('changed');
        }
    },
    change: function () {
        alert('change ' + this.id);
        $(this).addClass('changed');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Microfed/78UKh/52/).

Answer (score 0):

if ($(this).is(':checked'))....

if ($(this).attr('checked')) ...

EDIT: also, if all the checkboxes are for a "family", make sure only one can be checked by defining name=the-same-for-all-items and id=different ones for each item.

```
Ex:

<input type='checkbox' name='fruits' id='orange' >orange
<input type='checkbox' name='fruits' id='melon' >melon
<input type='checkbox' name='fruits' id='banana' >banana
<input type='checkbox' name='fruits' id='apple' >apple   
<input type='checkbox' name='fruits' id='...' >....

EDIT: if it was clicked: the id?

console.log($(this.id));
```

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify my question...I don't care at all if the checkbox is checked or not.  I care if it was clicked in to trigger the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing:

```
$("#foo", "#bar", "#fooCheckbox", "#barCheckBox").bind("click", function() {
   // do something here
   if($(this).is(":checked")) // do something extra here but focus doesn't happen here for checkboxes.
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="doSomething()">

  or

$("#foo","#bar","#fooCheckbox","#barCheckBox").click(function(){
    doSomething();
});
```